# How to do a double tap zoom in using PDFView's built in PageViewController?

Tags: swift, pdfkit

I'm building a pdf viewer using PDFKit and the built in page view controller that's in PDFView. I want to be able to double tap the page and zoom in on that part of the screen.

I've tried the `zoomIn:` method and that doesn't seem to work with the page controller. I've also tried creating a PDFDestination and then using `go(to:)` on the PDFView but it isn't zooming in. I've also tried going to the destination and then just changing the scale factor but that just zooms in on the center of the page.

Here is my tap gesture:

```
doubleScreenTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(zoomIn(_:)))
doubleScreenTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
doubleScreenTap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
containerView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleScreenTap)
```

Here is the function that is being called:

```
@IBAction func zoomIn(_ gestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
{
     if gestureRecognizer.state == .ended
     {
          if let currentPage = pdfView.currentPage
          {
               let point = gestureRecognizer.location(in: pdfView)
               let destination = PDFDestination(page: currentPage, at: point)
               destination.zoom = (pdfView.scaleFactor * 1.5)
               pdfView.go(to: destination)
          {
     {
}
```

I looking to be able to zoom in on spot that is tapped. Let me know if I'm doing anything wrong or any knowledge you have on this. Thanks

Comment: if you have found any solution to zoom into specific position then let me know. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60109438/7244281 Here is my question if you want to answer it.

Comment: @AqeelAhmad I haven't found a solution yet, my company made a decision that it wasn't necessary and I've haven't touched it sense. I did find out that not even Apple's PDF viewer (Books) supports this. They split the page up into thirds and depending on where you tap it just zooms and scroll to center that third.

Comment: I figured it out and wrote the answer stackoverflow.com/q/60109438/7244281

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken this feature is already available for PDFView. It will work if you will define scale factor

```
pdfView.minScaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
pdfView.maxScaleFactor = 4.0
pdfView.scaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this enable double tap to zoom
pdfView.enableDataDetectors = false;
```