# Zoom in to specific coordinates in PDFKit using swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, zooming, pdfkit

I am using `pdfkit` to open pdf file in my app.

> I want to zoom in to specific coordinates.

Let say Following is my pdf page and I want to zoom in to specific coordinates when user will click on pencil button.

[image]

After clicking on pencil button it should be look like following image.

[image]

I've searched a lot but couldn't find any proper solution for that. I don't want to use third party libraries to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using following code.

```
let documents = pdfView.document
    if let page = documents?.page(at: 0) {
        pdfView.scaleFactor = pdfView.scaleFactorForSizeToFit * 2
        pdfView.go(to: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300), on: page)
    }
```

This is the zoom in code to specific coordinates.

> There is one more thing that needs attention. You need to turn off
>   pagination `pdfView.usePageViewController(false)`.